Importing layer styling from QGIS into JupyterLab (Folium)
After having a lot of early success with Folium, I am wondering if it is possible to import QGIS layer styling directly and use them in Jupyter Lab? The styling could as well be saved within the Geopackage and used that way, maybe?
It possibly sounds absurd to people who actually know what they are talking about.

I don't know what styling Jupyter Labs use on their mapping, but QGis can export your styles as an international standard called SLD. If Jupyter/Folium don't yet support this standard then maybe you can encourage them to.
